# PyPDF2 add_bookmark arguments

Tags: python, pypdf

Hi Im very new in python and I would like to use few features from PyPDF, in particular, add bookmark with focusing on exact point in PDF:

writer.add_bookmark("Hello, World", 0, parent, fit= "/XYZ")

but got an exception:

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

Any suggestions on how syntaxis should look like?

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Comment: Also, you should include the complete Traceback